# Connecting Desktop to SQL Server 2012 SP1 via ArcGIS Server 10.1 very slow?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

We have just built and new ArcGIS/ArcSDE system with SQL Server 2012 SP1.  We are experiencing very long periods (up to 2 minutes) just to connect to the database in Desktop.  Desktop does connect and we can publish map services, but everything is painfully slow.  We have ruled out network issues, and wonder if we are missing something.  Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Have you re-indexed after upgrading?

Comment: analyzed and rebuilt with no change

Comment: Is it also slow if you create a query layer in arcmap?  You can create it via File>Add Data>Add Query Layer...

Answer (score 6):

Esri just released a patch addressing this exact problem. Identified as bug NIM082657 - When working with a SQL Server 2012 geodatabase and Geometry or Geography type data, ArcMap drawing performance is slower than it was using SQL Server 2008. This affects all rendering and editing operations.

Downloads and instructions here --
http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1954

Comment: Applied with no change.  Both ArcGIS Server and SDE database are on VMs, would that cause any issues?

Comment: It could explain if the VMs are under resourced - we run ours with VMs exclusively. Are you using a direct connect to the database or an SDE connection? Again, it shouldn't make too much difference but direct connect is the new recommended way. Do published services have the same problem when data is in fgdb? You can always open a support ticket with Esri as well.

Answer (score 3):

we had the same problem...and while not ideal the solution for us was to use SDE Binary storage type...super fast after that!